# Directory is Different When I Run PHP Script IN Scheduled Tasks Of Plesk

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, plesk

I use this `clear.php` script that remove all files and folders in correct `clear` directory:

```
<?php
 function deleteDir($dirPath) {
    if (! is_dir($dirPath)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("$dirPath must be a directory");
    }
    if (substr($dirPath, strlen($dirPath) - 1, 1) != '/') {
        $dirPath .= '/';
    }
    $files = glob($dirPath . '*', GLOB_MARK);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            deleteDir($file);rmdir($file);
        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

}
deleteDir('clear');
?>
```

when i run the code `mydomain.com/clear.php` it work and remove all files and folders but when i create a Scheduled Tasks in `plesk` and use this code it shows:

> Task "httpdocs/clear.php" completed with error in 0 seconds. See
>   details

and when i click the `see details` it shows:

```
Task "httpdocs/clear.php" completed with error in 0 seconds, output:

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: clear must be a directory in /var/www/vhosts/domain_name.com/httpdocs/clear.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/domain_name.com/httpdocs/clear.php(19): deleteDir('clear')
#1 {main}
thrown in /var/www/vhosts/domain_name.com/httpdocs/clear.php on line 4
```

Comment: Either pass your directory absolute or make sure the relative path starts from where your `php-cli` is located

Comment: thank u its worked.